# how do i translate this python code to matlab script?

Tags: python, matlab

I have been trying to convert this python code to Matlab script - but I could really use some help. I am rather new to the programming world as I don't have knowledge of the different commands.

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm8sq.png)

I have tried to convert word for word - but I failed desperately :(

```
def ranking(A):
     import numpy as np
     from mat1120lib import null

 if (A.shape[0] == A.shape[1] and len(A.shape) == 2):
     n = A.shape[0]
 else:
     n=0
     print "A is not a square matrix,aborting!"
     import sys
     sys.exit(1)
 tol = 1e-12
 for i in range(n);
     if (np.sum(A.T[i])-)>tol:
         print "A is not a stochastic matrix, aborting!"
         import sys
         sys.exit(1)
 S=1/float(n) * np.ones((n,n))
 m=0.15
 M=(1-m)*A + m*S
 n=null(M-np.eye(n))
 return n/np.sum(n)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here, instead of posting a *link to a picture*. This severely decreases your chances of someone helping you. And `help meee` as a username?

Comment: I tried to copy-paste it here - but it was all messy - not sure how to paste it and make it look decent and understandable...

Comment: To format your code, use fenced code blocks as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You will still need to include your attempt and a specific problem you need help with.

Comment: i tried something - and it is a bit understandable now or?

Comment: It looked fine until you removed it. Please do not deface your question, it makes it useless for future visitors.

Comment: The strategy here should be first identify what is the input and output of the method and what is the logic you need to get from input to output.  Then you can implement it as a matlab function.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want is to get the rank of the matrix you can simply use the Matlab build-in function

```
rank(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, translating line by line of code is a possibility and, in my view, being that the function on the picture is relatively short, is probably the fastest way of solving you problem.

On why source translators are not that common, check this thread:
**[Why aren't there automated translators from one programming language to another? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/why-arent-there-automated-translators-from-one-programming-language-to-another)**

Edit01: I commented the whole piece of code with the interpretation of what each line does, as follows. I hope it helps you understand what the code does in Python.

```
# This is defining the function "ranking", which receives the "A" argument
def ranking(A):
    
    # This imports the library/package NumPy
    import numpy as np
    
    # This imports the "null" function/type from the library/package mat1120lib; (this library was probably given to you by your teacher)
    from mat1120lib import null
    
    # This will check if the first and the second dimension of "" are equal, and check if the number of dimensions is two
    if (A.shape[0] == A.shape[1] and len(A.shape) == 2):
        # If so, it means "A" is a square array/matrix, so "n" gets the dimension of the size of the square
        n = A.shape[0]
    else:
        # Otherwise, "n" gets zero, you get a prompt and it aborts
        n=0
        print "A is not a square matrix,aborting!"
        import sys
        sys.exit(1)
    
    # You set tolerance "tol" to 10^-12
    tol = 1e-12
    
    # You start a for loop
    for i in range(n);
        # This checks if the sum of the elements of "A.T" in position "i" is greather than the tolerance "tol"
        if (np.sum(A.T[i])-)>tol:
            # If so, you get a prompt and it aborts
            print "A is not a stochastic matrix, aborting!"
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
    
    # "S" becomes a matrix of n-by-n elements, with which elements being 1/n
    S=1/float(n) * np.ones((n,n))

    m=0.15
    
    # "M" gets 0.85*A + 0.15*S
    M=(1-m)*A + m*S
    
    # Uses the output of the null function to overwrite the "n" variable
    n=null(M-np.eye(n))
    
    # The function ends and returns the result of this operation
    return n/np.sum(n)
```

Comment: but as I mentioned i am relatively new to Matlab so I have some difficulty understanding what NumPy, or A.shape[0] is in Matlab scripts...

Comment: I'd say that you are also relatively new to Python / NumPy, as it has nothing to do with Matlab.
Now with the code, I will try to help you translate.

Comment: Already edited my previous post. You can check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I really appreciate this help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough attempt at replicating the functionality in MATLAB. Grabbing the rank can be done as the other answer has stated.

```
A = [1/3 1/3 1/3; 1/3 1/3 1/3; 1/3 1/3 1/3];

%Checking if A is a square matrix%
[Number_Of_Rows, Number_Of_Columns] = size(A);

if (Number_Of_Rows ~= Number_Of_Columns)
fprintf("A is not a square matrix, aborting!\n");  
end

%Checking if the A is a stochastic matrix%
Total_Probability = 1;

Stochatic_Flag = 0;
Valid_Columns = 0;
for Column_Index = 1: +1: Number_Of_Columns
    
Current_Column = A(:,Column_Index);

if(sum(Current_Column,'all') == 1)
    Valid_Columns = Valid_Columns + 1;
end 

end


if(Valid_Columns == Number_Of_Columns)
    Stochatic_Flag = 1;
end

if(Stochatic_Flag == 0) 
    fprintf("A is not a stochastic matrix.\n")
end

N = Number_Of_Columns;
S = 1/N * ones(N,N);
m = 0.15;
M = (1-m)*A + m*S;
```